# google-play-services_lib.jar missing from SDK google_play_services lib folder

Tags: android, sdk, maps, google-play-services

I have a problem with *google-play-services_lib.jar* (I need it for Google Maps API v2 support) because it isn't added as library to my project. I imported the Google Play Services project and the *google-play-services.jar* appears on my project as a dependency, but *google-play-services_lib.jar* doesn't appear. I tried to delete and reinstall Google Play Services on SDK Manager.

In addition google-play-services_lib.jar is missing from *D:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs*. The only available files on that path are *google-play-services.jar* and *google-play-services.jar.properties*

Could anybody help me on it? Thanks and regards.

Edit: [This is the screenshot full-size link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5348174/EjemploGoogleMaps_build_path_error.png) (the image is very small in stackoverflow).

I attached a screenshot. [image: google-play-services_lib.jar missing error screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it (unbelievable) installing JRE 7 (I had JRE 6 installed) and with a rebuild of all the projects on workspace after the installation.

Comment: Interesting.  How does one determine the version of JRE? -- nevermind, I went to a command line (terminal for Mac): java -version <nl> java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-10M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)